# How do I create the following chart: like in app.nutmeg.com

Tags: html, graph, charts, highcharts

How do I create the following chart: like in www.nutmeg.com.

On setting parameters of years, initial capital, monthly contribution, and risk tolerance level - a chart comes up in the middle of the page - which auto-updates instantly on any change in the parameters.

I tried to find it in 
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-plot-bands 
but couldn't.

Below is the actual graph created:

[graph - autoresizes on changing parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H28T1.jpg)

Comment: 1) you'll have to provide an example that doesn't require us to go through a sign up routine, and 2) you'll need to give more effort and info on what you've tried to do and how

Comment: Edited to add the actual graph created

Comment: No, plot bands won't help you with this.  You need to calculate the actual data points to be plotted, and pass that to an *area* or *arearange* series - http://www.highcharts.com/demo/arearange

Comment: Hi, how do I add multiple series to this chart? 
Also, the datapoint in this demo is [1388538000000, 1.1, 4.7] for temperature range from 1.1 to 4.7 on 'Wednesday, jan 1 2014, 1:00 pm'. How to generate 1388538000000 from Wednesday jan 1 2014, 1:00 pm?

Comment: Look at any of the other demos with multiple series for how to add multiple series (ie  http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic ).  The 1388538000000 is a n epoch time stamp in milliseconds. Look at the *getTime()* javascript function. You can also send a Date,UTC() object in place of the time stamp. This is a useful epoch time reference: http://www.epochconverter.com/